# YCM is not working with .ycm_extra_conf nor compile_comands.json on Windows

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows, plugin-you-complete-me

I have problems using YCM plugged for C-family languages.
Here are what I have done:

1. project layout

```
-- build
-- src
   -- source file dir0
      -- include
      main.cpp
   -- source file dir1
      -- include
         -- dir1.h
      -- dir1.cpp
```

2. generate compile database running command on windows in directory build as below.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..\src\ -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

3. copy compile_commands.json to directory src.
4. I also generate configure file to src/.ycm_extra_conf.py with contents as below.

```
flags = [
    '-x',
    'c++',
    '-I',
    'dir1/include',
]


def Settings(**kwargs):
    return {'flags': flags}
```

I compiled both *clangd* and *libclang* during installation.
Since *clangd* is default selected by YCM, I switch *clangd* and *libclang* by manipulating vimrc setting  *ycm_use_clangd*.

After doing all these above,
The completion and syntax checking seem not working at all.

```
#include "dir1.h"  ==> diagnosed as header file not FOUND
```

And those functions and variables defined in dir1.h are diagnosed as undefined.

Comment: I would advise to be more specific with the error you are getting, to make it easier for other people to understand your problem. Also as stated by their [contact section](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#contact) I would suggest that you reference your question on their [glitter chat](https://gitter.im/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), there you should find more people knowledgeable about this plugin who should be able to help your faster.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved my problems using methods as below: 1. use compile_flags.txt instead of compile_commands.json and ycm_extra_config which are not supported on windows platform. 2. turn off the ALE plugin which may conflict with YCM.

Comment: It's great that you solved your problem! Could you please post an answer to your question explaining these steps (and accept the answer when you can) so that future users know that you found a solution and can try to use it too?